How light is light enough to be affected significantly by the "sensory puff of wind" effect of Druidcraft?
If I was 4 lbs and then I cast enlarge/reduce on myself to become 1/8 of my previous weight, becoming .5 lbs, would that be light enough to be significantly more affected by the sensory puff of wind made by druidcraft than a character weighing about 150 lbs?
Also, would wings make me be affected by wind more? If 2 characters are both 4 lbs and one has wings while the other doesn't, would it be easier to blow away the one with wings?

Note that "Gust of Wind" is the name of another spell. Perhaps you should rephrase to make it clear you are talking about "Druidcraft", which calls its effect "a puff of wind"

@TreeSpawned thanks for the heads up, I'll change that now

Related: What is the meaning of "harmless sensory effect" in Prestidigitation?

Not game rules oriented (so not even remotely an answer), but I think you underestimate how much wind would be needed to move a half pound character. Experiment: A living creature is essentially the same density as water, so if you weigh a half pound, that's almost exactly a cup of water. Take a small tupperware container, pour a cup of water into it, seal the top. Then turn a fan on it at full blast. If it moves at all, it won't be much, and it will take time (longer than the "instantaneous" length of the spell's effect).

@ShadowRanger sorry, I wasn't sure because I have a VERY weak fan. It probably shouldn't still work, and it barely does

Besides the Prestidigitation cantrip, this would also affect the Elemental Attunement discipline for Way of the Four Elements Monks.

A “harmless sensory effect” affects only the senses.
Druidcraft states:

You create an instantaneous, harmless sensory effect…

The word “sensory” here indicates that it affects only your senses, that is, the puff of wind is just light enough to feel it. It cannot blow you about, no matter how light you are.
As for wings, there are no rules for how a character with or without wings is affected by wind. That is, the rules related to weather that might mention wind don’t care if you have wings or not.

Rules as written, no. Rule of cool ... maybe.
While I certainly agree that this shouldn't be able to force a creature to move due to a sensory puff of wind, that doesn't necessarily mean that a creature that is trying to use that puff of wind to help them move wouldn't receive any advantages, especially if they're already in flight.
Consider this example:
The wizard's owl familiar is in danger and is within 30' of a druid.
The druid says "I'd like to use Druidcraft to make a puff of wind to give the familiar a tail wind so it can get away faster."
The DM considers and says "That's a cool idea, and the owl is pretty light. Since Druidcraft only affects a 5' cube, chose a space within 30' of you and cast Druidcraft, if the owl moves through that space on its turn, it'll get 5' of extra movement speed that turn."
I think that this interaction would be an appropriate application of the rule of cool, and would be at least worth asking (even though Rules as written, the spell doesn't say that it does this). As far as any objections to this violating the "harmless sensory effect" I would argue that proprioception is the feeling of movement and is a sensory effect, so as long as it is harmless it should be okay, but the DM would have to rule on how (the DM might say that the movement is only limited to the hairs on your arms).

I was mostly thinking about using it to escape Forcecage, squeezing through the bars because I'm 4 inches tall. Would you also let it work there? Like, enlarge/reduce on myself to become .5 lbs and 2 inches tall, squeeze into the gaps in the bars, and druidcraft to give the magical push because you can't escape with non-magical means

@Tasi: That's probably worth a separate question in its own right. I would say reducing your size to fit between the bars using any supernatural or spell power is a suitable "magical means" on its own, but I suspect it would be an interesting enough question to get some good answers.
